# Why is my font flickering whenever i hover/tap a link on mobile device?

Tags: typescript, next.js, netlify, google-fonts

I am using Nextjs to develop a website.
For fonts, i am using custom fonts sourced from fonts.google.com via the next/font/google package provided by NextJs [documented here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/fonts).

Whenever i click a navlink, the fonts flicker.
I am not able to debug this issue, any help regarding it is appreciated.

Video showcasing the issue - [Veed.io](https://www.veed.io/view/baf057eb-8086-4bc5-a610-8f35aa3e5688?sharingWidget=true&panel=share)

Note: I tried accesing the website on different devices, but it seems the problem only persists on mobile devices.
It maybe because of how mobile devices render fonts differently (just a guess).